# isalpha() and isdigit() always return 0

Tags: c, ctype

I have no idea why `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` keep doing this. No matter how I use them they always return a `0`. Am I using them incorrectly or is my compiler acting up?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//example of isdigit not working, it ALWAYS returns 0 no matter what the input is.
int main()
{
  int num=0;
  int check=0;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%d",&num);
  //Just checking what value isdigit has returned
  check=isdigit(num);
  printf("%d\n",check);
  if(check!=0)
  {
       printf("Something something");
       system("pause");
       return 0;
       }
  else
  {
       system("pause");
       return 0;
       }
}
```

Comment: Of course you are using them incorrectly. `0` is not `'0'`, `1` is not `'1'`, etc.

Comment: scanf("%d",&num); => scanf("%c",&digit);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isdigit` acts on an int, but it is supposed to be char extended to an int. You are reading a number and convert it to a binary representation, so unless your inout happens to be a value matching `0` - ´9` (i.e. 0x30 - 0x39) you will get false as a result.

If you want to use `isdigit()` you must use it on the individual characters from the string the user enters as the number, so you should use `%s`, or `%c` for single digits,  and loop through the string.

Example:

```
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);
check=isdigit(c);
```

or (quick and dirty example)

```
char buffer[200];
if (scanf("%s", buffer) > 1)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; buffer[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        check=isdigit(buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how this would be done, I'm new to programming so it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `scanf ("%d"...)` with scanf `("%c"...)` and the definition of `num` from `int` to `char`. You may also change the variable name, as `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` don't work with "numbers" but with "ASCII codes of characters" (which are indeed numbers), and the prompt message from `"Enter a number"` to `"Enter a character"`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the number character by character to `isdigit`. Replace `%d` specifier by `%c` in `scanf`.  And also remove the line

```
fflush(stdin);
```

it may invokes **undefined behavior** (if you are not on MS-DOS).

Answer (score 0):

You want to check a character not number. `0` and `'0'` are not the same. The first one is `integer`, second one is `character`.
Change on this:

```
  char character =0;
  int check = 0;

  printf("Enter a number: ");

  scanf("%c", &character);
  printf("%d\n",character);

  check = isdigit(character);
  if(check != 0) {
       printf("Something something\n");
       return 0;
  }
  else{
       return 0;
  }
```

In action:

```
Enter a number: 5
53 # ASCII code of 5
2048
Something something

Enter a number: a
97 #ASCII code if a
0
```